# How to set first N children height to its parent max-height jQuery or CSS(preferred)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically **prepended** divs (**`.class-row-notification`**) to another div (**`.class-append-con`**).
Now I want to set **first 5** divs **height** to its parent's **`max-height`** (Including `margin`, `padding`, `bottom-border` etc.).

**UPDATE**

Addition of first five div class (**`.class-row-notification`**)(**children div**) == **`max-height`** of class(**`.class-append-con`**)(**parent div**)

How to do that ? If through CSS, it should be cross browser.
I tried it through jQuery but everytime it gives me same **`height as 11px`** for the **`div.class-row-notification`**

**EDIT**:-
I removed the commented code from snippet and tried again, its **working here** but **not in my project why**?

I have following html -

```js
var notificationData = '[{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Shantaram : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640448139},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Spring : </b>How are you, <b>Shantaram</b> ? !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Suyog : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Balasaheb : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Ravi : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Nilesh : </b> Hello World !!! Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140}]';
      
      
     
  
  notificationData = JSON.parse(notificationData);
//  console.log(notificationData);
//  console.log(notificationData.length);
  var len = notificationData.length - 5 ;
  var heightCon = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < notificationData.length; ++i ) {
    contentText = jQuery(".class-notification-struct").clone(true);
    contentText.removeClass('class-notification-struct');
    /*contentText.find(".class-face-noti img").attr('src', notificationData.image);*/
    /*contentText.find(".class-name").html(notificationData[i].name);*/
    /*contentText.find(".class-notification-link").prop('href',notificationData[i].notificationLink);
    contentText.find(".class-notification-message").append(notificationData[i].message);
    var created_on_date = new  Date( notificationData[i].createdOn );
    contentText.find(".class-notification-time").append( created_on_date.toDateString() +" at "+created_on_date.toLocaleTimeString());
    */
     
    var created_on_date = new Date( notificationData[i].createdOn );
    var row_div =  "<div class='class-row-notification'>"
                    +"<a href='"+notificationData[i].notificationLink+"' class='class-notification-link' target='mainfrm' >"
                      +"<span class='class-notification-message'>"
                        +notificationData[i].message
                      +"</span>"
                      +"<span class='class-notification-time'>"
                        +created_on_date.toDateString() +" at "+created_on_date.toLocaleTimeString()
                      +"</span>"
                    +"</a>"
                  +"</div>";
    jQuery(row_div).prependTo('.class-append-con');
   
//  if( len <= i ) {
//    heightCon += contentText.outerHeight( true );
//    alert(heightCon +" : "+contentText.outerHeight( true ));
//  }
   
    
}
  calculate_height();
function calculate_height(){
var h = 0;
    $('.class-append-con > .class-row-notification:lt(5)').each( function( i ){
      h += $(this).outerHeight( true );
      alert( "Height of "+(i+1)+" div     :-  " +$(this).outerHeight( true )+" \nHeight Addition   :-  "+ h );
    });
    $('.class-append-con').css('max-height', h);
}
```

```css
.class-append-con {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.class-row-notification {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C2D0DB;
  position: relative;
}

.class-notification-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.class-notification-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  /* margin-left: 9px; */
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #3F4B57;
  line-height: 15px;
  max-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.class-notification-time {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-append-con">
</div>
```

Comment: *set first 5 divs height to its parent's max-height* What does this mean? parent's height will include the height of all the children.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks, I have updated question, please check update, ask me for any query

Comment: @gurvinder372 hope you get it, You can inspect elements for more clarification, thank you

Comment: So you want to ensure that only first 3 divs should be visible without scroll?

Comment: @gurvinder372 only **first 5** divs out of **total 6** should be visible **with scroll**,

Comment: You can run code snippet it is working here but not in my project...

Comment: Can you try to replicate the same issue here?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I don't know what is actual the issue, I tried to post code here, **same browser** , can it be jQuery version issue for **`outerHeight( true )`** ?

Comment: Are you using different jquery version in your project?

Comment: yes I'm using `version 1.10.2` in my project and `version 2.1.1` here

Comment: You can test here by including 1.10.2 version of jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160711/discussion-between-shantaram-t-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

I made a jQuery script to solve a similar problem some time ago. Mine was design to work with sibling elements, but it applies to parent-children elements too.

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".apply-max-height").map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
$(".apply-max-height").height(maxHeight);
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".apply-max-height").height("auto");
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".apply-max-height").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
    $(".apply-max-height").height(maxHeight);
});
```

**Updated for margin and other properties:**

```
var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".apply-max-height").map(function () {
    return $(this).height();
}).get());
$(".apply-max-height").height(maxHeight);
$('.children-element').css('margin', $('.parent-element').css('margin'));
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".apply-max-height").height("auto");
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $(".apply-max-height").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
    $(".apply-max-height").height(maxHeight);
    $('.children-element').css('margin', $('.parent-element').css('margin'));
});
```

This works on resizing too, add the properties that you want to "copy" the same way I did with margin and you should have no problems.

Add the "apply-max-height" class to all elements that you want and they will have the height of the tallest. Hope it works for you!

Comment: could you please explain the flow for me? thank you.

Comment: I don't want height of **tallest** of class **`.apply-max-height`** to all **`.apply-max-height`** class

Comment: sorry, you wanted the height to the max-height of it's parent, I missread that, give a couple of minuts and I update and explain how it works

Comment: calculate height of **first 5 divs**,  please check my **code snippet** it is **working here** but **not in my project**

Comment: your code is fine, or at least I'm not seeing any errors that could make it not work in your project...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the comments from question and tried again, its working here but not in my project **why**?

**EDIT**

**WHY?**
**I found the ISSUE :-**
I was not getting correct height because, my parent class **`.class-append-con`** (In this question), its parent class was **hidden**,
thats why I was getting `height()` as **0** and `outerHeight( true )` as fixed to **11px**

**Solution**
I have created new div **out of viewport** and then calculated height.

thank you people for your valuable time and efforts.

```js
var notificationData = '[{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Shantaram : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640448139},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Spring : </b>How are you, <b>Shantaram</b> ? !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Suyog : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Balasaheb : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Ravi : </b> Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140},{"notificationObjectId":null,"notificationId":null,"notifierId":null,"actorId":null,"entityId":null,"entityTypeId":null,"notifierName":null,"actorName":null,"message":"<b>Nilesh : </b> Hello World !!! Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!Hello World !!!","notificationLink":"#","createdOn":1512640449140}]';
      
      
     
  
  notificationData = JSON.parse(notificationData);
//  console.log(notificationData);
//  console.log(notificationData.length);
  var len = notificationData.length - 5 ;
  var heightCon = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < notificationData.length; ++i ) {
    contentText = jQuery(".class-notification-struct").clone(true);
    contentText.removeClass('class-notification-struct');
    /*contentText.find(".class-face-noti img").attr('src', notificationData.image);*/
    /*contentText.find(".class-name").html(notificationData[i].name);*/
    /*contentText.find(".class-notification-link").prop('href',notificationData[i].notificationLink);
    contentText.find(".class-notification-message").append(notificationData[i].message);
    var created_on_date = new  Date( notificationData[i].createdOn );
    contentText.find(".class-notification-time").append( created_on_date.toDateString() +" at "+created_on_date.toLocaleTimeString());
    */
     
    var created_on_date = new Date( notificationData[i].createdOn );
    var row_div =  "<div class='class-row-notification'>"
                    +"<a href='"+notificationData[i].notificationLink+"' class='class-notification-link' target='mainfrm' >"
                      +"<span class='class-notification-message'>"
                        +notificationData[i].message
                      +"</span>"
                      +"<span class='class-notification-time'>"
                        +created_on_date.toDateString() +" at "+created_on_date.toLocaleTimeString()
                      +"</span>"
                    +"</a>"
                  +"</div>";
    jQuery(row_div).prependTo('.class-append-con');
   
//  if( len <= i ) {
//    heightCon += contentText.outerHeight( true );
//    alert(heightCon +" : "+contentText.outerHeight( true ));
//  }
   
    
}
  calculate_height();
function calculate_height(){
var h = 0;
    $('.class-append-con > .class-row-notification:lt(5)').each( function( i ){
      h += $(this).outerHeight( true );
      alert(h +" : "+$(this).outerHeight( true ) +" : "+i);
    });
    $('.class-append-con').css('max-height', h);
}
```

```css
.class-append-con {
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.class-row-notification {
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 15px;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C2D0DB;
  position: relative;
}

.class-notification-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.class-notification-message {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  /* margin-left: 9px; */
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #3F4B57;
  line-height: 15px;
  max-height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.class-notification-time {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class-append-con">
</div>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the details instead of asking another question within answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18203263)

Comment: @Mamun I have asked new question here [How to set first N children height to its parent max-height using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47772391/3425489), please check