# How to set first N children height to its parent max-height using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have already asked a question and solved myself using `jQuery`, but I want to solve this using `CSS`.I'm using plain CSS.

Here is [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47693991/3425489).
@Mamun suggested me to ask a new question, so I have asked it again.
For details please refer question.

**Update From Previous question**

I have dynamically **prepended** divs (**`.class-row-notification`**) to another div (**`.class-append-con`**).
Now I want to set **first 5** divs **height** to its parent's **`max-height`** (Including `margin`, `padding`, `bottom-border` etc.).

Addition of first five div class (**`.class-row-notification`**)(**children div**) == **`max-height`** of class(**`.class-append-con`**)(**parent div**)

How to do that? If through CSS, it should be cross-browser.

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shantaram/d9cqbnot/)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you include more information about your question here? Thanks

Comment: ok I will add...

Comment: Can you include a not working jsFiddle example?

Comment: ok I will include that one also

Comment: Do you want the child's height to be the same height as the parent?

Comment: First 5 divs(children) height to its parent's max-height

Comment: Please check update ....

Comment: Did you check my js fiddle

Comment: not yet, will check later when get time

Answer (score 0):

I tried somthing here and i think this is what you mean

```
.class-append-con :nth-child(-n+5) {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[Here is the example you wanted](https://jsfiddle.net/tb74oo22/)

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: I've added an jsFiddle example

Comment: I will check, try and let you know